# Improper integral of an even function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

Given the improper integral below,

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^4e^{-x^4}dx $$

Is it correct that this is an even function since $x^4 \cdot e^{-x^4}$ is just a product of two even functions? If so, does this mean that *I* can also be equal to

$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^4e^{-x^4}dx$$

This is what I know so far and I'm still having a hard time on what to do next. Can anyone teach me on one of the approaches that I can make to evaluate this integral?

Comment: It is an exercise that my professor left for us to review. She told us to try and evaluate the said integral.

Comment: Give them some slack. That's not the worst formulation of the question by far.

Comment: You had provided sufficient information, apologies , I did not read your question properly

Answer (score 1):

You are right about even function property. If you substitute $t=x^4$, you will have an integral that suspiciously resembles the Gamma function.

Comment: So If I try to substitute that then is it correct that the resembling gamma function will be $\Gamma (2)$ ?

Comment: That's not correct. Be mindful when you calculate the power $n$ in $t^n e^{-t}$. It's not the same as $x^n e^{-t}$

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to tell me. So, if I try to substitute $t=x^4$ and then try to find dx. The corresponding integral will now be
$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} te^{-t}\frac{1}{4} t^{\frac{-3}{4}}dt$$

Simplifying this will give me the resembling gamma function $\Gamma (\frac{5}{4})$?

Comment: That's correct. An alternative way is to see that $x^4dx = \frac14x(4x^3dx)=\frac14\sqrt[4]t\,dt$